# What does this pattern ^[%w-.]+$ mean in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Just came across this pattern, which I really don't understand:

```
^[%w-.]+$
```

And could you give me some examples to match this expression?

Comment: That is pretty trivial, I suggest you read up on regex a bit.

Comment: [It throws an error.](http://regex101.com/r/zQ9qV5/1)

Comment: Actually, this comes from a lua script:    local return_domain_name = urlReq:match("^[%w-.]+$")

Comment: That's why the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) states that you should always include the regex flavor in the tags.

Comment: I removed the **regex** tag because Lua pattern is not regular expression, see [its tag infor](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua-patterns/info) for more information.

Comment: @YuHao Thanks for explaining. Great job editing the question and title also. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Valid in Lua, where `%w` is (almost) the equivalent of `\w` in other languages**

`^[%w-.]+$` means match a string that is entirely composed of alphanumeric characters (letters and digits), dashes or dots.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The character class `[%w-.]` matches one character that is a letter or digit (the meaning of `%w`), or a dash, or a period. This would be the equivalent of `[\w-.]` in JavaScript
- The `+` quantifier matches such a character one or more times
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Reference**

[Lua Patterns](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)

Answer (score 3):

Actually it will match nothing. Because there is an error: `w-` this is a start of a text range and it is out of order. So it should be `%w\-` instead.

> ^[%w\-.]+$

Means:

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `[%w\-.]+` match a single character present in the list below

  1. `+` Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  2. `%w` a single character in the list %w literally (case sensitive)
  3. `\-` matches the character - literally
  4. `.` the literal character .
- `$` assert position at end of the string

**Edit**

As the OP changed the question and the tags this answer no longer fits as a proper answer. It is [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) based answer.

As @zx81 comment:

- `%w` is `\w` in **Lua** which means any alphanumeric characters plus "_"

Comment: FYI your answer no longer works. It turns out that `%w` is `\w` in Lua. :)

Comment: Hi @zx81 I will edit it to put the information that it is POSIX based answer and it no longer fits as the OP changed the question. Thanks.